# Rails figaro gem - Don't know how to build task 'figaro:heroku' (Rails 4/figaro gem/heroku))

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

When trying to push changes on my application.yml file, I always use figaro gem via the command:

```
$ rake figaro:heroku
```

I had not done it for a long time but I tried today and I am getting this error:

```
mathieu@mathieu-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~/rails_projects/graalio_app$ rake figaro:heroku --trace
DEPRECATION WARNING: Support for Rails < 4.1.0 will be dropped. (called from require at /home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76)
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'figaro:heroku'
/home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:62:in `[]'
/home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
/home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

EDIT:

After a comment, checked on latest info on figaro gem: https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro#heroku-configuration

I tried:

```
$ figaro heroku:set -e production
```

But I get error:

```
/home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/figaro-1.0.0/lib/figaro/cli/task.rb:28:in `system': no implicit conversion of Array into String (TypeError)
```

Comment: Did you mean [`figaro heroku:set`](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro#heroku)?

Comment: i found the error: i had to put my config in strings

Comment: @NickVeys Just saved my day !

Answer (score 1):

The value should be in quotes.

```
production:
  EXAMPLE_VARIABLE: '[example_first_value, example_second_value]'
```

Answer (score 1):

This command worked for me:

```
bundle exec figaro heroku:set -e production
```